# trimming last paragraph from .txt file while doing fwrite

Tags: php

I am using below PHP code to write to my `wall.txt` file. It works fine but the problem is that `wall.txt` file size keep on increasing. i want to trim the `wall.txt` file once the new data is added after 3 paragraphs.old paragraph will be deleted while new one are appended

here is php file

```
  <?php

    $joke = $_POST['AndroidString'];


     $complexString = ($joke . "|" . date("l") . ", " . date("jS \of F Y h:i:s A"));
   $endLineStericks = "****";


        $registrationFile = fopen("wall.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

   fwrite($registrationFile, $complexString);
  fwrite($registrationFile, "\n");
 fwrite($registrationFile, $endLineStericks);
 fwrite($registrationFile, "\n");

 fclose($registrationFile);


   ?>
```

here is text file

> Boy: The principal is so dumb!/-%/Girl: Do you know who I am?/-%/Boy:
>   No.../-%/Girl: I am the principal's daughter!/-%/Boy: Do you know who
>   I am?/-%/Girl: No.../-%/Boy: Good! *walks away*|Friday, 05:23:04pm
>   **** Boy: *calls 911* Hello? I need your help!/-%/911: Alright, What is it?/-%/Boy: Two girls are fighting over me!/-%/911: So what's your
>   emergency?/-%/Boy: The ugly one is winning.|Friday, 05:36:19pm
>   **** The closest Iâ€™ve been to a diet this year is erasing food searches from my browser history./-%//-%/Lollzzzzz :p|Friday,
>   05:44:35pm
>
> ---

Comment: This is basically the technique for *log rotation*. Example snippet and explanation can be found [in this article](https://snippetsofcode.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/rotating-log-php/).

Comment: do you want to keep only three paragraphs in `wall.txt file` for  all the time?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes . latest three paragraph which will be on top  and old one should be deleted

Comment: why the last paragraph in your example text file doesn't end up with `"****"` as it should?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  yes it ends with that. i think while editing some moderator removed that. it ends with ****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `file` and `array_slice` functions:

```
define("WALL", "wall.txt");
$joke = $_POST['AndroidString'];

fopen(WALL, 'a') || die("Failed to open file!");
$contents = file(WALL); // gets file contents as array of strings(lines)

$complexString = ($joke . "|" . date("l") . ", " . date("jS \of F Y h:i:s A")). PHP_EOL;
$endLineStericks = "****" . PHP_EOL;

$contents = array_merge($contents, [$complexString, $endLineStericks]);

 // if there were at least three records(including end stricks) in wall.txt
if (count($contents) > 6) {
    $contents = array_slice($contents, -6); // getting last three records
}
file_put_contents(WALL, implode("", $contents));
```

Comment: full content of that txt file is deleted and nothing is written

Comment: "this line gives error array_merge" - so what is the error?

Comment: dreamweaver shows syntax error. i tried with $contents = array_merge($contents, $complexString, $endLineStericks); error gone but complete data from txt file is deleted and nothing is added

Comment: you are using the old PHP version. Change that line to the following: `$contents = array_merge($contents, array($complexString, $endLineStericks));`

Comment: wowwwwwwww awesome. it works like a charm.thanks.is there anyway we can allow like button in text ?????